# In Windows, can I see what apps were open on background or foreground in the past?

Tags: windows, journaling

Is it possible to see some history for applications that were open in the past (also see, if it was background or foreground)? For example, if I want to know if viber was open as foreground a week ago or something like this.

Comment: There are applications for such usage monitoring, no doubt. Seems like information untrusting corporate employers might like.. However Windows does not keep such information by default nor does it provide any native support for such logging. Some basics, such as executables starting, might be logged (depending).

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you for your answer. Tell me please, can I see if it was at least somehow launched? I opened "event", saw some ssh journal, but no apps like chrome or viber..

Comment: @user2864740 This is not 100% true, Windows 10 has internal usage tracking of applications. You can find bits of it in the registry.